# Can the carbon nanotubes in Vantablack absorb sound?

Tags: visible-light, acoustics, nanoscience

Say you wanted to create a sensory deprivation room surrounded with the Vantablack material. As well as absorbing light, would the carbon nanotubes also be able to absorb sound, eliminating the shape of the walls and floors of an anechoic chamber?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1511/1511.04543.pdf  
I don't know about the exact properties of the carbon fibres related accoustics but this paper discusses things in quite details. It talks about damping parameters of various substances including carbon fibre in the "results and discussions" section. Take a look :)

Comment: @Sad_lab_rat I don't think it will really come down to the carbon itself but rather the shape of the tubing, and whether they can absorb sound or not. Carbon fibers and carbon nanotubes are very different in shape. I could be mistaken on the carbon having little to no effect on the sound absorption, my knowledge on this is limited. Thanks for the read :)

Answer (score 1):

https://www.acoustics.asn.au/conference_proceedings/INTERNOISE2014/papers/p124.pdf This research paper here has done the experiments with the CNT that you were curious about. Along with the performance of the CNT they've also compared it to normal materials used nowadays. The shape will definitely play an important role. The CNT used here(from my preliminary reading of the article) is multi-walled CNT nano-forest. The comparison is with glass-wool and melamine foam. 
They've also reported the comparison for different frequencies of sound. [image: comparison plot]

Comment: I hope this helps or at least gives you a direction. You can follow the links to the citations to do an in-depth literature review of the matter

Comment: Those dips down to the Absorption of Melamine foam is interesting.  Must be some sort of a resonance common to all geometries of CNT there...  It's fairly dense stuff, at 43kg for a meter sized cube.   I had pictured it as aerogel realm of density...

Comment: Perfect, the CNT used in the Vantablack material is also multi-walled.